# Krom *unukornulo*, kiuj vortoj kun *-ul* havas nehomajn signifojn?

Tags: word-meaning

Mi ĵus lernis la vorton *unukornulo*, kaj pensis al mi, ke ĝi estus erara ĉar ne temas pri homo.

Lau [*ReVo*](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/ul.html#ul.0o) *-ul* tute ne havas nur homa signifon, sed la fundamentaj tradukoj uzas la vortojn *person, Person, człowiek, особа*, kiuj (certe la germana kaj la angla - mi ne certas pri la pola kaj la rusa) signifas *homo*.

Ĉu ekzistas, krom *unukornulo*, nehomajn ulojn?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PIV havas iomete malsaman difinon en tri partoj. La unua difino ja estas nur indivduo, kaj tio povas nur metafore esti besto. La dua difino tamen uzas ĝin por difini kategorion de besto, kaj tio ja havas plurajn ekzemplojn:

- amebuloj
- araneuloj
- duvalvuloj
- mamuloj
- skvamuloj
- sponguloj

Comment: Kaj kiu povus forgesi la fifaman forfikulon!

Comment: "Forfikulo" ne enhavas la sufikson "-ul-".